# Batch delete files in subfolders with spacing in filenames

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have one directory with around 100 subdirectories, which include images. I then have a .txt list of images I need to delete from these folders. 
Since there are a few thousands, I'm looking for a way to batch delete these using bat file.
But the problem is that my files are in subfolders and subfolders and also filenames include spaces.

**Example:**

```
MainFolder/Subfolder One/Image Sunshine.jpg<br>
MainFolder/Subfolder One/Image Cloudy.jpg
```

I've tried multiple options of **del**, also by putting all paths in txt file inside double quotes. But nothing deletes them.
Any ideas how to delete only the selected ones from all subfolders? 
Renaming or deleting spaces is not an option, since I would have to reupload the remaining images back in the same form as current.

Comment: We need to see an example of your .txt list content together with the multiple batch file attempts in order to help you to fix one or other of those attempts!

Comment: `del "MainFolder/Subfolder One/Image Sunshine.jpg"`

Comment: @Stephan: your option returns: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: `del "C:\MainFolder\Subfolder One\Image Sunshine.jpg"`? (using the correct folder delimiter `\\`)

Comment: @mamatata, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question.

Comment: This question is not about programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, and therefore should be asked here:
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is by using an `FOR` statement to read each line of the text document as a string.

For the removal of the files we can use the `DEL` command along with the `/s` switch to search all sub-directories.

- **/P** - *Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.*
- **/F** - *Force deleting of read-only files.*
- **/S** - *Delete specified files from all subdirectories.*
- **/Q** - *Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard*
- **/A** - *Selects files to delete based on attributes*

The following script will remove all `file.extension`'s from the *list.txt* file from all sub-directories in the directory tree including the execution directory. This will also remove them if they have spaces in the name as `"%%G"` is quoted.

**Batch File:**

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (list.txt) do (del /s /q /f "%%G")
```

**Command Prompt:** (Be sure to `CD` to the main directory!)

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %G in (list.txt) do (del /s /q /f "%G")
```